# Count common friends/nodes

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have the table1 below and want to make a table that shows how many friends Ent1 has in common with any other person from Ent1.

Eg A (short for AAA) has friends B,C,D,E,F while B has friends A,C,E,F. They have C,E,F in common so  the outcome should be AAA BBB 3

Can this be done in acces/SQL? I have no clue ...

Table1

```
Ent1 Ent2 link
AAA BBB friend
AAA CCC friend
AAA DDD friend
AAA EEE friend
AAA FFF friend
BBB AAA friend
BBB CCC friend
BBB EEE friend
BBB FFF friend
CCC AAA friend
CCC BBB friend
CCC EEE friend
CCC FFF friend
DDD AAA friend
DDD KKK friend
DDD LLL friend
EEE AAA friend
EEE BBB friend
EEE CCC friend
FFF AAA friend
FFF BBB friend
FFF CCC friend
KKK DDD friend
LLL DDD friend
```

The outcome should be :

```
AAA BBB 3
AAA CCC 3
AAA DDD 0
AAA EEE 2
AAA FFF 2
AAA KKK 1
AAA LLL 1
BBB CCC 3 etc...
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, it can be done.  I kinda hate your table and I feel like it could be normalized into two tables to work better but I'm not coming up with how right now.  So here's how to do it with your current table in SQL mode:

```
select s.Person_1, s.Person_2, count(*) as tot
    from
    (select 
        a.Ent1 as Person_1
        , a.Ent2 as Common_friend
        , b.Ent1 as Person_2
        from [Table1] as a
    inner join [Table1]  as b
    on a.ent2 = b.ent2
    where a.ent1 <> b.ent1) as s
group by s.Person_1, s.Person_2
```

The way this works is that the subtable `s` gets all the links you want to count by self-joining your table (the `where a.ent1 <> b.ent1` makes it so you don't count a person as linked to themself).  Then the outer query counts the number of links between pairs.  This code will give pseudo-duplicates as it counts a link between AAA as the first person and BBB as the second person as different from BBB as the first person and AAA as the second person.  I'm not coming up with an easy way to fix that, but you the data you want will be there.

Comment: I understand your sentiment about the table, but its where I have to start from. The code looks sweet , I put it to the test asap, thanks for giving me more than just a base to start from. Me too I think copying the table and work with both might solve some problems
I also just realized that the output is only possible if no more than 1000 record for the number of results would be (1000*1001)/2 = 500500 records.
Thanks again !

Comment: Tried the SQL and it errors on the !. Why is it in there? Removed it and not get the output shown in the example.

Comment: `!=` is not-equal for TSQL, I forgot that Access uses `<>`.  I've updated my answer accordingly.